# hidden input value is void

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

This form have a hidden input, when i send the form to my api, the value of the input is void. Isbn and packId are properties of a *book* model,
Why the *packId* value is void?

```
<form class="general-form col-lg-10" #bookForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(bookForm)">    
   <p>
    <label>ISBN</label>
    <input type="text" name="isbn" #isbn="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="book.isbn" class="form-control" required />          
   </p>    
    <input type="hidden" #packId [(ngModel)]="book.packId" name="packId" value="5bd5cdd8bf7ba21ea799b726">    
    <input class="submit-book btn btn-success"  type="submit"  [disabled]="!bookForm.form.valid" />    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need a hidden input? The value is probably coming back as empty because you are using ngModel: it's assuming the value of the field is book.packId from your model, not the "value" attribute.